# nodejs express missing file router/user.js

Tags: node.js, express

Hi hope someone can help.
 been playing with Node JS and Express trying to get this http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/ tutorial with no luck. but I think I may know why I have had no luck with getting it to work. It seems after i create the project with express i'm missing a file mainly route/user.js
This in the output from the build.

- create : test3
- create : test3/package.json
- create : test3/app.js
- create : test3/public
- create : test3/public/javascripts
- create : test3/public/images
- create : test3/public/stylesheets
- create : test3/public/stylesheets/style.css
- create : test3/routes
- create : test3/routes/index.js
- create : test3/views
- create : test3/views/layout.jade
- create : test3/views/index.jade
- dont forget to install dependencies:
  $ cd test3 && npm install

  - The output in the tutorial included a file /router/user.js

I’m not sure why it happened or how to fix it.

any help would be great thanks

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct version of Express installed. You also should include whatever error output you are getting.

Comment: Just checking that `/router/user.js` is a typo on your question and you had intended on `/routes/user.js`